# mkdir /.docker: permission denied error when trying to build docker image from Jenkins pipeline on Mac

Tags: docker, jenkins, permissions, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I'm running Jenkins for MacOS (using Homebrew) and Docker Desktop on Mac.

When I try to build docker image for Python app from Jenkins pipeline, the following error is reported:

```
+ docker build -t <docker image name> .
ERROR: mkdir /.docker: permission denied
```

Jenkinsfile snippet:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        ...
            stage("Build Docker Image") {
            agent {
                docker { image 'docker:24.0.5' }
            }
            steps {
               script {
                dockerImage = docker.build("<docker image name>:${env.BUILD_ID}")
               }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Dockerfile (from root path on GitHub repository):

```
FROM python:alpine3.18
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . /app
CMD ["flask", "run","--host","0.0.0.0","--port","5000"]
```

In previous stages, docker containers are successfully used.
**EDIT:**
I needed to apply this workaround: https://harshityadav95.medium.com/how-to-setup-docker-in-jenkins-on-mac-c45fe02f91c5
because I have faced `docker command not found` issue before this one.
I assume that the user for Jenkins does not have permissions to write in ./docker dir but I'm not sure which user this is.

Every help is welcome. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: First follow these steps for [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/). If that doesn't fix it , run  ps aux | grep '/usr/bin/daemon' | grep 'jenkins' | awk {'print $1'}`  and find jenkins user , log in as that user and see if you can run docker run commands manually

Comment: Hi @AlirezaPourchali, thank you for your response.
I'm able to run docker commands without _sudo_ so Docker is already manageable with a non-root user.
Regarding second fix, when I run the command you have mentioned, nothing happens: 
    ps aux | grep '/usr/bin/daemon' | grep 'jenkins' | awk {'print $1'}`
    pipe pipe pipe bquote>

Comment: ps aux | grep '/usr/bin/daemon' | grep 'jenkins' | awk {'print $1'}

Comment: run the above command , previous one is wrong sorry for the misspell

Comment: Hi @AlirezaPourchali. Unfortunately there is no output for this command:
    brew services start jenkins-lts
    ==> Successfully started `jenkins-lts` (label: homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts)
    ps aux | grep '/usr/bin/daemon' | grep 'jenkins' | awk {'print $1'}
    
Thanks!

Comment: sorry i cant understand your output, could you rephrase that or update your question

Comment: I have started jenkins with homebrew and immediately after that I ran your command. Basically there is no output of the command (it's empty). Thank you @AlirezaPourchali!

Comment: Here you go @AlirezaPourchali:
`brew services start jenkins-lts`
`==> Successfully started jenkins-lts (label: homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts)`
`ps aux | grep '/usr/bin/daemon' | grep 'jenkins' | awk {'print $1'}`
``

Comment: did you give a specific user for jenkins while installing? im not on mac so i cant be sure about that      
another thing , i dont think its got to do with docker permission , the jenkins user might not be able to create a directory                  

check which directory is it running the docker command 
you can see that with adding something like running `pwd` in the pipeline to see it in the log

Comment: @AlirezaPourchali no, I didn't specify the user while installing Jenkins with Homebrew. These are the simple steps to install and run Jenkins on Mac (official doc): `brew install jenkins-lts` `brew services start jenkins-lts`
How exactly do you mean to use `pwd` in pipeline? I have also updated Dockerfile  to the question description. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: im not familiar with jenkins syntax , run `pwd` command in your pipeline before the docker command . pwd command prints the working directory , you should be able to see it in your pipeline log

Comment: Hi @AlirezaPourchali, this is the output of the `pwd` command when I run it immediately before `docker build` command: `+ pwd` `/Users/<user>/.jenkins/workspace/deploy-python-web-app`. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved reported issue by setting HOME to ${env.WORKSPACE} inside mentioned Jenkins stage:

```
environment {
                HOME = "${env.WORKSPACE}"
            }
```

I hope it helps someone.